# How can I pass user-input to implement an alarm clock?

Tags: c

I'm currently working on creating an alarm clock in C. The gist of it is pretty simple, I want to:

1. Take in user input for the desired alarm time
2. Compare it to the local time
3. Decrement the timer in seconds, and print when it reaches the alarm

However, I'm having some trouble and have been stuck for awhile now. Here's what I have so far:

```
int u_input(int* uhour, int* uminute, int* usecond);
void sc_alarm();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int uhour, uminute, usecond;
  u_input(&uhour, &uminute, &usecond);
  sc_alarm(uhour, uminute, usecond);
}

int u_input(int* uhour, int* uminute, int* usecond)
{
  printf("Enter H M S:");
  scanf("%d %d %d", uhour, uminute, usecond);
}

void sc_alarm(int uhour, int uminute, int usecond)
{
  struct tm *tm;
  time_t ctime;
  ctime = time(NULL);
  tm = localtime(&ctime);

  int difference, alarm_total, local_time_total;
  int chour = tm->tm_hour;
  int cminute = tm->tm_min;
  int csecond = tm->tm_sec;

  difference = alarm_total - local_time_total;
  alarm_total = (uhour * 3600) + (uminute * 60) + usecond;
  local_time_total = (chour * 3600) + (cminute * 60) + csecond;

  do
  {
    printf("Time left: %d seconds\n",difference);       
    difference--;
    sleep(1);
  }
  while(difference > 0);

  printf("Alarm!\n");

}
```

Comment: why not comparing the localtime vs alarm time, as your alarm could have issues with daylight saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating the difference before the values that you need to subtract.

Replace

```
difference = alarm_total - local_time_total;
alarm_total = (uhour * 3600) + (uminute * 60) + usecond;
local_time_total = (chour * 3600) + (cminute * 60) + csecond;
```

with

```
alarm_total = (uhour * 3600) + (uminute * 60) + usecond;
local_time_total = (chour * 3600) + (cminute * 60) + csecond;
difference = alarm_total - local_time_total;
```

Also, you should note that if you are on Windows, `sleep` takes it's arguments in milliseconds, and if you are on Linux or Unix `sleep` takes it's arguments in seconds, so you need to modify the `sleep` function accordingly.

Comment: That worked. I did forget to mention that I am indeed coding in Linux. Thank you Rishikesh for your help!